# Return array with all children from a parent table Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im using LARAVEL 5.7 and i have 2 tables called "parent_table" with "parent_id,parent_name" and "children_table" with "children_id,children_name". And i have 2 models with the same names of the tables with the following code:

Parent Model

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\children', 'children_id');
}
```

Children Model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\parent', 'parent_id');
}
```

I have a controller with this code

```
$data = App\parent::with("children")->get();
return $data;
```

But it returns me only the first children of every "parent". I want to know what i need to add to the code to get all the children of every parent.

I already try to get all the "parents" and the foreach all the "children" but it would be to many request to database. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours i found the solution. I didn´t know that it was important to make the select to the foreign key... that's why my query wasn´t working.

Final Parent Model

```
 public function children()
 {
    return $this
                ->hasMany('App\children',"parent_id")
                ->select(
                    "children_id",
                    "children_nombre",
                    "parent_id"//I wasn't selecting this guy
                )
                //->with("children2") // With this i got the way to concatenate a lot of subchildren map :D
                ;
 }
```

Final children model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\parent',"parent_id","parent_id");
}
```

Controller

```
$data = App\parent::
                select(
                    "parent_id",
                    "parent_nombre"
                )
                ->with("children")
                ->get();

    return $data;
```

I learn something new today, I hope this answer helps to other laravel learners too

Comment: Actually, there's no need to select the foreign key. The reason your first approach wasn't working is because you were passing in the wrong foreign key 'children_id' in your Parent Model's children() function. You need to pass in the column that will be used as a foreign key in the child's table i.e 'parent_id'

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 @foreach($parents as $parent)
{
  $parent->children();
}
```

This should return a collection from the Children model. For more info you can look here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Im not sure if its recommendable to iterate a eloquent query because it will open and close a lot of sql conecctions

Comment: I understand, you wanna do this with one query? Well, i think the way to go is to use "With" like you did. Try this: Parent::with('children')->find($id); And take a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads    . The eager loading session must have everything you need

Answer (score 0):

Using `with` as you did in your exemple will work. Maybe you have to put 'children' in the $appends array on your model.

```
namespace App;
class Parent {
  ...
  protected $appends = ['children'];
  ...
}
```

this will appends the children result when the model are transformed into array

Comment: In App\parent i have the hasMany and App\children i have the belongsTo already

Comment: ok, so please correct your post because the two functions are mixed